# How to attach and open Firefox browser when launching a debug session in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger, firefox-developer-tools

Using VS Code I have no issue when debugging my app in Chrome or Edge. When I start debugging, the Chrome/Edge browser opens up and I see my app. I can set breakpoints and debug my app with no issues.

But now I want to debug using Firefox, so I installed the "Debugger for Firefox" extension (not sure if this was needed or not), checked off "Enable Remote Debugging" in the developer tools section in the Firefox browser, created a new launch configuration in launch.json below and then started a debugger session.

**Problem** - Starting the debugger looks fine in VS Code console, but Firefox (browser) doesn't open or get attached to my debug session.

**Question** - Do I have my configurations below set correctly or is there something else I need to do to have VS Code open Firefox and attach to it? I read through the details of the extension page, but not sure if I need to do anything else? Do I need pathmappings? Do I need to do something else in Firefox?

```json
"compounds": [{
  "name": "Server/ClientFirefox",
  "configurations": ["Launch .NET6 (no web)", "Launch Firefox"]
}],
"configurations": [{
    "name": "Launch Firefox",
    "type": "firefox",
    "request": "launch",
    "reAttach": true,
    "url": "https://localhost:4200",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client"
  },
  {
    "name": "Launch .NET6 (no web)",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "build",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/API/bin/Debug/net6.0/API.dll",
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/API",
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "env": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    "sourceFileMap": {
      "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
    }
  }
]
```

**FYI** - here is what my launch configurations for Chrome looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "Launch Pwa-Chrome",
  "type": "pwa-chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "https://localhost:4200",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client"
},
```

Comment: The sample for the extension shows `"file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"` rather than your `url` and `webroot`.  And it works for me.  try changing to `file` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working...

```js
// modified to work - removed "reAttach" and modified other properties to other similar configs w/ port:4200 and client folder
{
  "name": "Launch Firefox",
  "type": "firefox",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "https://localhost:4200",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/client"
},

// created by VS Code
{
  "type": "firefox",
  "request": "launch",
  "reAttach": true,
  "name": "Launch localhost",
  "url": "http://localhost/index.html",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

Comment: THANK YOU.  I would love to know why this is required.  I have been looking for this solution for a while.  Does no one use firefox any more?  Makes me sad.