# Chrome hangs when debugging in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, freeze

When hitting F5 to debug a C# .Net Core website the Chrome browser that automatically launches will hang.  This started after I upgraded to VS 2022 17.5.2 today (from 17.2 something).  I was able to debug fine in the new VS version until it crashes during debugging and VS hung.  I closed the browser window and VS and restarted, and from that moment on I have this hanging issue with Chrome.

The Chrome browser will display the starting URL but no response will display and the developer tools network show it is waiting for server response.

If I copy the URL and paste into a new tab (in the same Chrome instance) it will also hang.

If I copy the URL and paste into a new Chrome instance (started from taskbar icon), it will correctly load the page.  This other instance is correctly firing breakpoints in my code.

I am using the latest Chrome Version 111.0.5563.65.

I am debugging using IIS Express, in process.

If i put break points in the controller and view i can see them processed, but no response makes it back to the browser window.

I have tried clearing all Chrome caches (several times).   I have restarted the computer.

Using "start without debugging" works as expected and the web application runs fine.  Obviously this prevents me from achieving any debugging so doesn't resolve my issue.

I am hoping someone knows why the automatically launched chrome browser is not getting a response from the server when debugging? yet other Chrome instances work fine?

Comment: Same issue started for me today. Disabling tools debugging "enable JavaScript debugging for asp.net (chrome, edge, and ie)" allows the project to run and you can debug js using chrome dev tools.  Hopefully a fix for this is coming.

Comment: Same issue started for me today. I'm using Edge. I had no problems prior to upgrading to 17.5.2.  FireFox seems to work fine (so far).

Comment: i wish i didn't jump straight into 17.5.2 when  it became available!  Disabling script debugging works - also i have noticed that only certain javascript libraries cause the issue.  Bootstrap, MetisMenu, Node-waves,  ExcelJs, FileSaver, jspdf all cause the hanging.  Other large libraries like JQuery, Devextreme, JQuery-validation can all be loaded OK.  Both Edge and Chrome fail (they are both Chronium now), but Firefox works

Comment: I had the issue with VS 17.5.0.  The factor that broke it for me was upgrading to 111 on Chrome or Edge.

Comment: I don't know yet. I am still trying to get it fixed for me. I can debug with MS Edge, but not Chrome. I was able to debug in Chrome until sometime yesterday morning - now I can't. I was briefly able to yesterday evening, but it was a fluke. There was a Windows update applied yesterday to my pc. I wonder if this caused it?  "2023-03 Cumulative Update for Windows 11 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5023706) today this morning."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update 3/15/2023 @ 5:22PM Central** 
The error seems to occur when you hit a breakpoint in chromium browsers (Chrome/Edge). I switched to Firefox and haven't had an issue all day.

---

**Update 3/15/2023 @ 10:22AM Central** 
Edge just hung after starting/stopping debug multiple times, then modifying code.

---

**Original** 
We were having issues running debug in Chrome Version 111.0.5563.65 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Visual Studio 2022 for both 17.5.1 and 17.5.2 version. The problem went away once I updated from 17.5.1 to 17.5.2. Between that temporarily fixing the problem and rebooting the computer not fixing the problem, my co-worker figured it may be something hung via caching.

That's when he thought to clear the hidden .vs folder. It was still a temporary fix and needed to be repeated often. @Tobias Andersson and @Slick Van Tanoid answers suggesting trying another browser was a great workaround. I haven't had the issue appear in the Edge browser during debug.

Sorry for adding an answer, I don't have the reputation for commenting or liking answers.

Comment: Hi Ryan.  Using other browsers and disabling script debugging are all good work aroudns, but your answer is as close as we can get to fixing it while we wait for the MS dev team on the links 4JTB provided below.  Deleting the .VS folder allows it to work until you add a debug point then it locks again.

Comment: Hi Flouen, seems as though it's chrome's issue. I believe they are working on undoing the breaking release in 112.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1604

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it for me! I wasted a lot of time yesterday waiting for it and trying to fix it yesterday and today! I had updated to the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 but that didn't fix the problem. Deleting the .vs folder does! Thanks!

Comment: I have upgraded to VS 17.5.2 and still get this issue. Edge version 111.0.1661.41 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Chrome 111.0.5565.65 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Upgrading Edge to version 111.0.1661.44 seems to have fixed the problem for Edge per @Slick Van Tanoid's answer.

Comment: I installed https://brave.com and restarted VS. In the debug launch drop down in the toolbar I selected WebBrowser->Brave and F5ed again. Works great :). Hope it works for you too.

Comment: This started happening to me today using Visual Studio 2022. I noticed there was a VS update available so I updated to 17.5.2 and the issue went away.

Comment: Clearing .vs folder - worked like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

I've just this minute updated Edge to the Version 111.0.1661.43 (Official build) (64-bit), and then enabled JavaScript debugging in Visual Studio. The hanging has now stopped, and I can debug JavaScript again. Please try updating your Edge (go into "Help and feedback->About Microsoft Edge", and it will auto-update). Looks like Microsoft just pushed out an update which may fix your problem. It seems to be working for me.

Comment: I just tried it with the current version (.44) and it appears to have been fixed.

Comment: Just tried with latest Edge and latest Chrome and both work for me.  Chrome; Version 111.0.5563.111 (Official Build) (64-bit), Edge: Version 111.0.1661.51 (Official build) (64-bit). Deleting .vs folder didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

In VS, do you have "Script Debugging (enabled)"? Not sure if you're experiencing the same problem, but it seems like when (Java)Script debugging is enabled, it causes the webrowser to hang. Try disabling it.

I've noticed this problem has appeared in the latest versions of VS, and i've not found a solution to it so far.

However, I have noticed that if you use Avast Browser or Brave browser as your web browser when developing websites, then you don't get the problem. However, you still can't debug JavaScript.

Further, I'm not sure whether the problem is with VS. Instead, it may be a recent update of Windows that has caused it, because I updated to the latest version VS a few weeks ago, found JS debugging was broken, then reverted my VS version so I could continue JS debugging. However, my PC recently updated Windows, and now JS debugging is broken again.

Comment: Yes Script Debugging (Disabled) resolves the issue, and i can debug in Chrome dev tools.  It would be nice to do it all back in VS again.

Comment: Disabling Script debugging didn't fix it for me. Deleting the .vs folder did!

Answer (score 2):

I solved in this simple vay:
All you have to do is delete the .vs folder.

Restart the solution, IT WORKS!

Comment: This temporarily works but eventually the solution will start to hang again until you upgrade Edge to .43 or above.

Answer (score 1):

It works again using Google Chrome Dev (https://www.google.com/chrome/dev/).  Hopefully it wont be too long til this filters down to the official public version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Chrome Version 111.0.5563.111 on 03/22/2023 is working for me.

Comment: It's not hanging chrome anymore, but I'm having all kinds of strange (new) breakpoint issues in my `vue` app.

Answer (score 0):

I started having this issue today after updating to the latest VS 2022 version 17.5.2. I tried rebooting and changing startup browsers as well but it did not help.

***However***, I was able to do the following things and was able to resolve the issue permanently with script debugging is still enabled. I am not sure which part(s) actually do the trick to fix the issue:

1. Delete the .vssscc file from my project folder and the hidden .vs folder as   well.
2. Set "2" Default Browsers from in VS 2022 under the "Browse With" menu option in the VS toolbar. (Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge) - Setting 2 browsers ALWAYS launches both browsers in debugging mode but they work the 1st time, every time.
3. Opened task manager and ended any Microsoft Edge WebView2 or Edge Browser tasks running in the background and also one named "Microsoft Malware Protection Command Line Utility" (I had never really noticed this thing before today)

Answer (score -1):

Another option I found (for Ajax/jquery based application)

1. Debug -> Delete all breakpoints
2. Start the application (F5)
3. wait for the first page to load.
4. Add a breakpoint where you need it and continue as usual

Also,
At a front-end javascript "debugger;" the command works.