# Web page does not load when running in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

When running a MVC app in Visual Studio 2022 Professional Edition, the web app usually loads successfully in the Edge browser when running it.  Recently, however, when running the app the Edge Browser opens, displays that page's title in the first tab, but then hangs and never fully loads the page.

We found that if we disable "Script Debugging" (screenshot below), this resolves the issue and the page then loads fine in the Edge browser.  Needless to say, however, we NEED Script Debugging to be enabled.

This issue happens when other browsers are targeted too (e.g. Chrome).  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others are reporting the same or similar issues with VS and script debugging lately.  See [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75740738/chrome-hangs-when-debugging-in-visual-studio-2022) and [VS Community post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/When-Debugging-Browser-does-not-finish/10311194?ftype=problem&amp%3Bq=script%20debugging&q=javascript%20debug%20chrome&sort=newest)